# MLFlow: How to load weights from model and continue training

Tags: mlflow

As ask many times before I'd like to continue / finetune training of an existing model.
We use MLFlow to store the model.
How can I load the weight from an existing model to the model and continue "fit" preferable with a different learning rate.